# Using both ProGuard and R8

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-r8

I want both ProGuard and R8 to perform code shrinking and optimization: I'm sure R8 after a year of development cannot be as cool as ProGuard after 15 years.

`android.enableR8` flag enables R8 **instead of** ProGuard.

Is there any way to use both tools using official Android toolchain, i. e. Gradle with Android plug-in?

Answer (score 2):

There is no supported way of running both R8 and ProGuard inside Android Studio. I suggest that you compare the results of the two shrinkers, and decide which one you want to stick with. If you see R8 producing larger output than ProGuard please let us know, by file a bug report using [this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788&template=1025938).

Comment: For my 'hello world' application R8 in `fullMode` produces slightly smaller DEX that ProGuard. But size is not the only metric to judge about. R8 lacks many optimizations implemented by ProGuard. ProGuard was before Android and will be after it, it is not discontinued, some more features are being added.